# How to clear JavaScript variables on page reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, scope, reload

I was doing some javascript scope tests and I faced with a problem with the values of the variables.

First I executed this code:

```
function changeName() {
    name = "Ronaldinho";
}
changeName()
console.log(name);
```

The output in console was: Ronaldinho

Then I performmed only this code:

```
console.log(name);
```

The output in console still was: Ronaldinho

I was using Google Chrome. I tried to clean cache, all options of page reload (ctrl + F5/ shift + F5 / ctrl + R/ shift + R / Right click in reload icon and "Force reload and clear cache"), clear the cache, console clear, enable de option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)".

It only works when I close and open a new tab.

Comment: Aye? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The scope is not preserved when you refresh. What did you do exactly, ran that code inside a script.js, then deleted it, replaced it with simply `console.log(name)`, saved the .js file, reloaded the browser and still got the same output? Because such a thing is not possible

Comment: @BBog I belived this to be the case too...so I opened up Dev Tools (from this page) in Chrome and pasted in his first block and ran it, and then I Ctrl + F5'ed the page, and ran the console.log and it did indeed preserve the name.

Comment: @Mark. I see, I got the same result. But you did it inside the console, not with a separate JS file. It's not the same thing.

Comment: I created an html file and wrote this code in a simple script tag. Then I wrote the first code, then I changed the file with the second code, saved and reloaded the page.

Comment: @GoldShip That's why it gets fixed if you switch to a new tab...see Magus' answer. The window object is not destroyed or recreated on a refresh because the window still exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you forget the `var` keyword in javascript, the variable will be created in the root object. In a browser, the root object is `window`. So you'll find your variable in `window.name`. If you want to delete it you can do `delete window.name`

EDIT : In the Chrome console, the executed code is protected from that. Chrome use an other object than `window`. You'll find your variable in `this.name`. So you can delete it with `delete this.name`.

Comment: I just tested that in Chrome Dev Tools, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does exist a way of clear the window insted of close and open a new tab??

Comment: See my edit. Chrome console use an other object than `window`

Comment: @Magus Still doesn't fly. After running delete this.name; in the console, this.name still equals the original value.

Comment: See axelduch response. I think this is your problem

Comment: @Magus Interestingly, the console value 'this' appears to only be an alias for window.

Answer (score 5):

Change the name of your variable, try "myName" instead. Since you never use the "var" keyword, `name` is in the global scope.

But something else happens: `window.name` is already taken! Because a window has a `name` associated with it. (see [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for further information)

Or better: In 99% of cases use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, the rest of the time, don't declare a variable (meaning `window[anyVariableName]` is not truly declaring a variable, rather than defining a new key to the window object, implicitly available everywhere in a browser's context).

The final code (if you want to keep the variable `name`):

```
var name;

function changeName() {
    name = "Ronaldinho";
}

console.log(name); // undefined
changeName()
console.log(name); // "Ronaldinho"
```